# Splunk Token for multiple Microservices

Tags: java, spring, splunk

I am researching to integrate splunk with my service running in Docker. In my case, the splunk enterprise runs on a different host.

One way to achieve this is to use docker's built-in splunk logging driver. I see that one of the configuration parameter is `"splunk-token": ""` which is the splunk Http Event Collector token that needs to be created in the Splunk enterprise.

My question is - Would I be required to create separate HEC tokens for each of the microservice projects. Let's say, if we have 10 microservices projects running which need to integrate with Splunk. Does that mean I would have to create 10 different tokens in Splunk enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

A single HEC token can be used by all projects, if that's what you want.  Since each token can have separate default index(es), you can use different tokens to direct traffic to the desired index.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will try that out.